# AS3 - URLload local files with absoute path

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to open local hard drive files inside AS3.  I'm getting a security error with this code:

```
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("c:\slushy.mp3");
```

Is it possible to URLload an absolute path on the hard drive?

Edit:  so this appears to be a sandboxing issue.  Drat.  Is it possible to load the local file via PHP and send to flash?

Comment: There are ways to load local files in Flash. What exactly are you trying to accomplish (other than opening an arbitrary file without user permission)?

Comment: If you work with local files a lot, perhaps Adobe Air is a better solution? It needs installation on the client's PC, however.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server language, so the final protocol is http.

The you must to acces by file:/// to the local file, but if you want to share the resources over Internet, you must upload your files to folder in the root of site.

By example: http://www.mysite.com/music

Then you can load the file:

```
    var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.com/music/slushy.mp3");
```

Requisite: you must to create the directory "music" in server web application directory and upload the file.